# comparing two generic objects if the one is "greater" or "smaller"

Tags: java, list, generics

I want to generate a binary tree with key-value pairs in their nodes.

In my binary tree I want to implement nodes at the beginning with an `insert` method, which implements a new left node if the key is smaller than the key of the current node. Then if there is already a left node it will check again for it. The same logic follows for right/greater node inserts.

I wrote my code first using the `int` type because it's way easier for me to test my code before I use generics (new topic for me). It worked when using `int` but I am unsure how to compare two generics with themselves by using `<` or `>`.

```
public ListCell<Type> checkKey(Type key, ListCell<Type> checkCell) {
    ListCell<Type> newCell = null;
    if (key < checkCell.key && checkCell.left != null) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't know if it's worth saying but I'm creating my binary tree with a self-coded list.
Above you can see my current checks but I can't compare my given key now with `checkCell.key` because of them not being numbers.

So how can I compare the keys in generics if they are "smaller" or "greater" than the other for my implementation in a binary tree?

Comment: *" I am unsure how to compare two generics with themselves by using < or >"*  You can't.

Answer (score 9):

You would need to ensure that your generic type implemented the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, and then use the `compareTo` method instead. Java does not support overloading the `>` operator (or any operator overloading, for that matter).

As per [the documents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)), `compareTo`:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

An example (that you'll have to map on to your exact code), assuming that `key` is your item you will store in your node, and `checkCell.key` is your node

```
int compareResult = key.compareTo(checkCell.key);
if (key < 0) { // it goes on the left }
else if (key == 0) { // it is the same }
else { // it goes on the right }
```

In your `compareTo` method you need to decide what fields in your class determine it's "ordering". For example, if you have a `size` and `priority` field, you might do:

```
@Override public int compareTo(Type other) {
  final int BEFORE = -1;
  final int EQUAL = 0;
  final int AFTER = 1;

  if (this == other) return EQUAL;

  if (this.size < other.size) return BEFORE;
  else if (this.size > other.size) return AFTER;
  else { // size is equal, so test priority
    if (this.priority < other.priority) return BEFORE;
    else if (this.priority > other.priority) return AFTER;
  }
  return EQUAL;
}
```

Comment: but i would need to override it am i right?
I already implemented the comparable interface but wasn't sure how to use the compareTo properly(read the doc on oracle.com)

Comment: for your type, implement a meaningful `compareTo` that obeys the rules in the docs. Now if `newItem.compareTo(node)` is `-1, 0 or 1` then `newItem` is: less than (put it on the left); equal to; or greater than (put it on the right) of `node` (in that order).

Comment: but how can i compare my item to the node properly? how can i check in my compareTo method if the key is smaller, equal or greater than the key of the compared node? equal could be done with the equals method? but I don't know how to do smaller or greater.. can you maybe gimme a hint?

Comment: see my edit. It will depend entirely on your chosen rule for what is less than, equal, or more than.

Comment: well i understand your code (atleast i think) but i think it won't help me that much :/ first thing is that my key is also a generic so in your first code sample it won't work again I think because of key not being able to be compared if it is smaller than 0 or greater than 0. (i think you mean if(compareResult < 0) ?) second thing is that I don't have a size or priority(if it is the same it will be overwriten) my attributes I'm using are my nodes(created via ListCells (ListCell = Node didn't know the correct name^^)) a key and a value all of the generic type

Comment: another comment because of the number of chars. I got operators for my first node, previous node and for every left,right node of a selected node. I implemented an iterator to iterate over my list with left and right command to go left or right but not sure if this helps checking for the "size"

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Ctse4NT.png this is how my ordering should be (numbers in the node is the key) 3rd post sorry because I can't edit the older ones..

Comment: I think you should ask a new question about how you should implement `compareTo` for your specific class. Questions are "free", and you'll get more people looking at it, it will also be focused on that problem instead of your question about operator overloading

Answer (score 6):

Bounded type parameters are key to the implementation of generic algorithms. Consider the following method that counts the number of elements in an array T[] that are greater than a specified element elem.

```
public static <T> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e > elem)  // compiler error
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

The implementation of the method is straightforward, but it does not compile because the greater than operator (>) applies only to primitive types such as short, int, double, long, float, byte, and char. You cannot use the > operator to compare objects. To fix the problem, use a type parameter bounded by the `Comparable<T>` interface:

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

The resulting code will be:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

[bounded type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html)